# How does the energy output vary?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, physical-chemistry

If you combust 5 grams of two different fuels keeping in mind that one burns faster than the other, will their **individual** **total** energy outputs be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need more information to answer this properly, namely how much energy is available from the combustion reaction, per gram.  If that's the same for both fuels, then yes the energy output will be the same.  But as you've said they're two different fuels, this is unlikely to be the case.  To give an example, consider burning 5 grams of paper, compared to burning 5 grams of jet fuel.  Do you imagine they'd release the same amount of energy?

The point here is the energy released, depends on the number of chemical reactions that can take place, multiplied by the net change in energy per reaction.  Notice that the speed of reaction hasn't entered into this at all.